# Bind values inside a multiple for loop in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have two loops in my template file.i am trying to bind second value using first loop value.But i am getting error.

```
<tr *ngFor="let splitdata of mf.data">
  <td *ngFor="let slitup of searchFieldsslitup">
    {{splitdata.slitup.headName}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: how does the mf.data look like and what do you want to bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access the properties by their name:

```
<tr *ngFor="let splitdata of mf.data">
  <td *ngFor="let slitup of searchFieldsslitup">
    {{ splitdata[slitup.headName] }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: {{ splitdata[slitup.headName] }} works for me...thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could also try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let splitdata of mf.data">
  <td *ngFor="let slitup of splitdata">
    {{slitup.headName }}
  </td>
</tr>
```